# Azure Machine Learning Workbench not opening

Tags: azure, workbench

No installation errors, but nothing happens when I double-click on the desktop shortcut. Got the below error when I fired the exe up from the command prompt:

C:\Users\murugappanr\AppData\Local\amlworkbench>AmlWorkbench.exe

```
C:\Users\murugappanr\AppData\Local\amlworkbench>
module.js:472
    throw err;
    ^

    Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\murugappanr\AppData\Local\amlworkbench\resources\electron.asar\browser\init.js'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
        at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
        at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
        at run (bootstrap_node.js:431:7)
        at startup (bootstrap_node.js:155:9)
        at bootstrap_node.js:551:3
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you run the CMD as administrator?

Comment: Yes, both as admin and normal user. Both gave the same error. Just remembered that the Python directory in amlworkbench is gone. Disappeared right after the installation completed.

Comment: Check if the `electron.asar` exists in the foler`C:\Users\murugappanr\AppData\Local\amlworkbench\resources\.`

Comment: Checked and the answer is no, unfortunately.

Comment: Did try uninstall and reinstall the workbench ?

Comment: Yes - twice. No luck.

Answer (score 0):

This issue should be caused by losing `electron.asar` file for the Workbench.I reproduced your issue by deleting the `electron.asar` file. I got the same error as yours.

**Solution:**

Step1. Ensure there is no some safety or else software can auto delete the file. If there is one, try to add the file into the protection or white list.

Step2. Install the Azure Machine Learning Workbench on another machine. Than Copy the `electron.asar` file to your machine.

Additional, If you have lost more files, even the whole resource folder, try to copy all lost files from another machine. I'm not sure if it works for your scenario.

Please let me know if it helps.